# How to block launching other application on the device in Android

Tags: android, service, android-launcher

I am basically looking for a solution which is required blocking the other apps. So in my app which will run as a service, will always check for two different state: Active and Inactive. If the state is active, I need to block other apps. "Block other apps" can be like this:

1. While clicking any app suppose facebook, it should not open that particular app. Instead it should show my activity which can not be closed by pressing menu button, back button or home button.
2. Can it be possilble to write launcher app? Which will check the state all the time. If state is Active, launcher app will be automatically launched, else android default launcher app will work as usual. Is it possible that launcher app can not close by pressing back button or home button?

I have tried this. Till now using the service, I am able to get the launch time of the other apps. And on that time, I am able to show my activity. But the apps which i clicked is still opened on the background and also my activity is closing when I am pressing the back button or Home Button.

How can I do this?

Also want to know if anyone tried the second option.

Thanks in Advance.

-Arindam

Answer (score 1):

For Your Ask
1,you can override onKeyDown method

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME==keyCode){
         //DoThings
     }
     //For more read the Android api
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

2,you have no need to check anymore,launcher app is a Delegator,it's always in your app,just like google launcher.

Comment: In this way home key can not be disabled after Android 4.0.